# GCC compiling a dll with __stdcall

Tags: c++, gcc, name-decoration

When we compile a dll using __stdcall inside visual studio 2008 the compiled function names inside the dll are.

FunctionName

Though when we compile the same dll using GCC using wx-dev-cpp GCC appends the number of paramers the function has, so the name of the function using Dependency walker looks like.

FunctionName@numberOfParameters or == FunctionName@8

How do you tell GCC compiler to remove @nn from exported symbols in the dll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

__stdcall decorates the function name by adding an underscore to the start, and the number of bytes of parameters to the end (separated by @).

So, a function:

```
void __stdcall Foo(int a, int b);
```

...would become _Foo@8.

If you list the function name (undecorated) in the EXPORTS section of your .DEF file, it is exported undecorated.

Perhaps this is the difference?

Comment: Thanks roger for the reply, it turned out that the problem was that another developer placed a DEF file into the project. This DEF file told the linker the naming conventions to use inside the DLL. This is the reason why we were getting a different library name even with the same calling convention.

The solution turned out that one of our developers had removed WINAPI from the header file when creating his own DLL for a project. This caused windows visual studio to revert back to its default calling convention of __cdecl (/Gd).

Answer (score 7):

Just use `-Wl,--kill-at` on the gcc command line, which will pass `--kill-at` to the linker.

References:

- http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options
- http://www.geocities.com/yongweiwu/stdcall.htm

Comment: I can confirm, that --kill-at works with mingw-w64 toolchains.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias` to your linker options in GCC. This will ensure that both function names (decorated and undecorated) are present and can be used as alias.